# Cannot install Autodesk Eagle on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, autodesk

I had downloaded the tar.gz file for the linux version of the Autodesk Eagle software. I extracted in my home directory which created the folder eagle-8.2.2. I opened this folder in terminal and as instructed in the Autodesk intallation [webpage](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/how-to-install-autodesk-eagle-on-windows-mac-and-linux/), I entered the command "./eagle run" and pressed **Enter**.

This opened a splash screen where Loading was written and the followinf message had appeared in the terminal

> ./eagle: /home/rishav/eagle-8.2.2/lib/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-client.so.3)
>   Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /home/rishav/eagle-8.2.2/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
>   Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /home/rishav/eagle-8.2.2/qtwebengine_locales. Trying fallback directory... Translations MAY NOT not be correct.
>   [0701/014149:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(291)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
>   Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /home/eagle/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/resources. Trying parent directory...
>   Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /home/eagle/Qt/5.6/gcc_64. Trying application directory...
>   Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /home/eagle/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
>   Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /home/rishav/eagle-8.2.2/libexec/qtwebengine_locales. Trying fallback directory... Translations MAY NOT not be correct.
>   Qt WebEngine resources not found at /home/eagle/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/resources. Trying parent directory...
>   Qt WebEngine resources not found at /home/eagle/Qt/5.6/gcc_64. Trying application directory...
>   [0701/014149:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(291)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale

The installation was stuck there for a long time instead of going to the login screen. I can see a few error messages in the readout but I don't know what to do about them as those directories like "/home/rishav/eagle-8.2.2/translations/" does not exist.

What am I supposed to do?